# Fetching Data in ReactJs from Yii2 APi

Tags: reactjs, yii2

I am quite new to React and I am working with Yii2 API. I want to get data from my API using React component. I can visibly get this data using PostMan. 
When I Try with React, the fetch statement doesnt return any data. Any help on this will be appreciat as I have spent a couple of this trying to figure out this bug

Here is my ReactJs Component fetch function

```
fetchPoll(){
  console.log("before json")
    fetch(URL_HOME, { method: 'GET',
                      headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log("before json2")
        this.setState({pollTrendings:json})
        console.log("before json3")
        console.log(this.pollTrendings)
    })
     console.log("endingjson")
}
```

from my console, I can not get the console.log("before json2) and console.log("before json3"). This means that my fetch statement is not successful.

Below is my API endpoint

```
public static function allowedDomains()
{
    return [
        '*',
    ];
}  

public function behaviors()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

            // For cross-domain AJAX request
            'corsFilter'  => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                'cors'  => [
                    // restrict access to domains:
                    'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)

                ],
            ],

        ]);
    }
public function actionTrendingmusic(){

    //find all the rows in the trending table with status current and type music
    $trending = Trending::find()
                                ->where(['status'=>'current', 'type'=>'music'])
                                ->all();
    return $trending;
```

}

Comment: Can you check the `Network` tab in your browser and see if the request is going out?

Comment: @izb I get "Cached responses: 0 Total requests: 17Size: 13,644.15 KB Transferred Size: 10,100.00 KBTime: 1.64 secondsNon blocking time: 1.59 seconds"

Comment: ooh, I got the error. the request was not send  because I omited the "http" from my api url :( so silly